# How to collect google site logged in username

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm creating a simple Google Site that has nothing on it but a form to collect respondent's information.  The reason I'm using Site instead of just a Google Drive form is because I need to offer respondents the ability to upload files. Couldn't figure out how to do it with Google Drive form.

The site (or form) will only be shared with users in my institution which uses GoogleApps and everyone will need to log in their GoogleApps account to view the site. I'd like to know how to capture or collect the logged in GoogleApps username viewing the site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If all your users are within a Google Apps domain, then collecting the username is rather straightforward. Use

```
var username = Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();
```